# Identify remove and count duplicated columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I am trying to identify and remove duplicated columns. I have this R codes that works for removing duplicates but fails printing the duplicated columns.

I would like to have as output a list of the duplicated columns by group.

In this case I would like the output to be something like:
 `[[x1,x4,x5,x8], [x2,x7]]` .

As I need to know which column and how many times is duplicated

```
# 0. Crear data set ficticio 
my_df <- data.frame(x1 = c(1:5),
                    x2 = letters[1:5],
                    x3 = seq(10,50,by=10),
                    x4 = c(1:5),
                    x5 = c(1:5),
                    x6 = LETTERS[1:5],
                    x7 =letters[1:5],
                    x8 = c(1:5) )

 # 1. Find the Duplicated Columns
 duplicated_columns <- duplicated(as.list(my_df))


 # 2. Show the Names of the Duplicated Columns
 colnames(my_df[duplicated_columns])


 # 3. Remove the Duplicated Columns
 my_df[!duplicated_columns]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function `duplicated`:

```
lst <- as.list(my_df)
dup_cols <- duplicated(lst) | duplicated(lst, fromLast = TRUE)

unname(split(names(my_df)[dup_cols], sapply(my_df[dup_cols], toString)))

[[1]]
[1] "x1" "x4" "x5" "x8"

[[2]]
[1] "x2" "x7"
```

Answer (score -3):

To find and remove duplicate columns in R, you can use the following code:

```html
# 0. Create a fictitious dataset
my_df <- data.frame(x1 = c(1:5),
                     x2 = letters[1:5],
                     x3 = seq(10,50,by=10),
                     x4 = c(1:5),
                     x5 = c(1:5),
                     x6 = LETTERS[1:5],
                     x7 = letters[1:5],
                     x8 = c(1:5) )

# 1. Find Duplicate Columns
duplicated_columns <- my_df[duplicated(my_df) | duplicated(my_df, fromLast = TRUE)]

# 2. Display Duplicate Column Names
names_list <- list()
for (col in names(duplicated_columns)) {
   group <- which(names(my_df) == col)
   if (length(group) > 1) {
     if (!exists("names_list", where = 1)) {
       names_list <- list()
     }
     if (length(names_list) < max(group)) {
       names_list[[max(group)]] <- col
     } else {
       names_list[[max(group)]] <- c(names_list[[max(group)]], col)
     }
   }
}

# 3. Show Duplicate Column Groups
output_list <- unlist(names_list, recursive = FALSE)
print(output_list)

# 4. Remove Duplicate Columns from Data Frame
my_df <- my_df[!duplicated(my_df) | !duplicated(my_df, fromLast = TRUE)]
```

The above code will generate a list of duplicate column groups and will also remove those columns from my_df

Comment: This code returns NULL and does not remove duplicated columns

Comment: from 4 parts the 2nd part can be changed like :

  names_list <- list()
for (col in names(my_df)) {
   if (col %in% names(duplicated_columns) && !col %in% unlist(names_list)) {
     group <- names(my_df)[which(names(my_df) == col)]
     names_list[[length(names_list) + 1]] <- group
   }
}

Comment: does not work sorry

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).